# Open excel settings via VBA

Tags: excel, vba

is it possible to open excel settings via VBA: I have created a custom button that should open the configuration settings of excel.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Untested code but you probably need to use sendkeys for this.
Please note that sendkeys can mess up stuff. Use it with care.

```
' open file (ALT + f)
Application.SendKeys("%f", true)
' press t for options
Application.SendKeys("t", true)
```